# How do I pass a variable from a view to a JavaScript function?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a website that has a JavaScript function I want to call passing in a value when a hyperlink is clicked. I'm generating some table rows in the view like this:

```
foreach(var e in Model.Collection)
{
    ...
    //This is just an example piece of code that tries to get the big picture
    //across. I want to call the JS function below passing in the ShipAddress property
    <td><a href="javascript:popup(@e.ShipAddress)">@e.ShippedDate</a></td>
    ...
}
```

And I have a JavaScript function like this:

```
function popup(data)
{
    $('#lblShipAddress').text(data.Address1);
    ...
    // rest of code to fill out labels in a div
    $('#divShipInfo').dialog('open');

}
```

I'm having issues getting the ShipAddress property(which has a number of properties i.e. Address1, Address2, etc.) passed into the JavaScript function from the View. The
 href="javascript:popup(@e.ShipAddress)" part doesn't work, and I've also tried using data attributes e.g.

```
<a href="javascript:popup();" data-shipAddress="@e.ShipAddress" />
```

but have not had any luck.

EDIT: Added some clarity to what I'm looking for. If at all possible I would like to only pass the ShipAddress property to the function.

Comment: MVC is not built-into JavaScript. Which one are you using?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm using MVC4 and C#.

Comment: The simplest solution seems to be to JSON serialize the data object using `data-shipAddress="@Json.Encode(e.ShipAddress)"` so it's passed to your method as an object - however, having that much data inline in an html attribute seems rough - you should probably test.

Comment: So is it not possible to pass the object from the View to the JavaScript function and access the properties there?

Comment: @RickDailey I got it to work changing my link to be:
<href="#" onclick="popupShipping(@JSON.Encode(e.shipAddress))" /> Thank you for the suggestion. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Sure, glad it worked!  As noted, my main concern with posting as an answer is making sure the inline JavaScript works in your target browsers and that the data does not make your page weights unwieldy.  Also, make sure your address object does not have fields you do not want to be seen by your users.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, just `@e.ShipAddress` is going to return the equivalent of .ToString(), which is not useful for your method as input.  Instead, you'll want to JSON serialize the object like:

```
<a href="javascript:popup(@Json.Encode(e.ShipAddress))">@e.ShippedDate</a>
```

This will result in final html something like:

```
<a href="javascript:popup({ Address1: 'Blah', Address2: ... })">@e.ShippedDate</a>
```

And so the popup method would have access to the object values.

Warning: make sure there aren't any fields on your address object that you don't want leaked to your end consumers - Json.Encode will serialize all public properties.

Answer (score 0):

First, I wouldn't use **javascript:popup()** - try [one of these](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp).  Also, don't use the quote marks with the razor syntax, or it probably won't evaluate the variable.

If none of that solves it, then it could be a timing issue.  I've had a lot of trouble with MVC-controlled pages (as opposed to use JavaScript/jQuery and callbacks) not updating when you think they will.  For some reason, the MVC controller deals with the button press, runs the server-side code, updates the page objects... THEN releases control to JavaScript, et. al.

It basically makes using JavaScript with the built-in Microsoft controls almost impossible.